# numpy library in Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed anaconda and pycharm. I was working on juypter. I installed numpy but when I am running my program in jupyter then its showing that 'there is a problem in importing numpy libraries, first uninstall it and then install again'. can anyone help me that why this error is and how I can uninstall numpy in anaconda and how again correctly I can install it?? and do I need to install it in a specific drive?

ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.

Comment: If you have installed `anaconda`, which comes bundled with numpy, how did you install `numpy` again? This probably broke something in your setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anaconda comes with Python and 100+ popular packages, including numpy.  My guess is that you used pip to install another copy of numpy into your Anaconda installation.

You can check by running:

```
pip freeze
```

If you see two copies of numpy, you have a problem.  You can try to uninstall it using

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

But my guess is that it may break your installation.  Your best bet is to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda.  (You should also consider upgrading to Anaconda3 with Python 3.).

Going forward, if you are going to use Anaconda, you should use Conda to install packages whenever possible.  I.e.

```
conda install numpy
```